# How to read pkcs12 content in golang, i have example in PHP

Tags: php, go

There is a decryption and signature interface. I want to move from PHP to Golang. The PHP function is as follows:

```
function getSignature($param){
if (is_string($param)) {
    $file_private = 'file.p12';
    if (!$cert_store = file_get_contents($file_private)) {
        return "Error: Unable to read the cert file\n";
    }
    $signature = "";
    $algo = "sha256WithRSAEncryption";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $private_key_file = openssl_pkcs12_read($cert_store, $cert_info, $password);
    if ($private_key_file)
    {
        $private_key = $cert_info['pkey'];
        openssl_sign($param, $signature, $private_key, $algo);
        return htmlentities(base64_encode($signature));
    }

}
return false;
}
```

I want to use golang to achieve.
How can I convert into golang?

**SOLVED**

This is what actually my code in golang:

```
func Sign(privateKey *rsa.PrivateKey, data string) (string, error) {
h := crypto.SHA256.New()
h.Write([]byte(data))
hashed := h.Sum(nil)

sign, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, crypto.SHA256, hashed)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
return base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(sign), err
}


func read_keys() {
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.p12")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)

}
password := "PASSWORD"
privk, _, err := pkcs12.Decode(b, password)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
pv := privk.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
sign, _ := Sign(pv, "Your String Data")
fmt.Print(sign)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did it fail? StackOverflow is not a coding service..

Comment: That's example using php, on my system written in golang, i want to convert functions like openssl_pkcs12_read and openssl_sign in golang @nijm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12) is the package you're looking for

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*in)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

privateKey, certificate, err := pkcs12.Decode(data, *password)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

pv := privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
signature, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, rypto.SHA256, hash)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Yups, I got privateKey and how to do the rest? @danicheeta

Comment: `openssl_sign($param, $signature, $private_key, $algo);
return htmlentities(base64_encode($signature));`

Comment: glad could help